# What happens if I found a city next to a previously razed city

Tags: civilization-5

So I was playing a game last night where I was going for a Space Victory, toward the end of the game I went to war with Germany.  After dropping the A-bomb on Hamburg and razing it to the ground I sent my workers in to clean up the mess.  My conscience got the better of me.  All that to brag and ask a question.

During clean up I notice there was a tile with like 10 food and 8 hammers where Hamburg once laid.  If I built a new city next to it would I get those production values?  Or would it reset when the new city was founded?  Or is it just a graphical bug?

Note it did not seem like a graphical bug because hovering over it the tooltip said something like

City Square
10 Food
8 Production

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Whether it is just visual or actually functional, sounds like you're in a great position to tell us!

Comment: yes, please try it and tell us. that is what load and save should be for (not for changing history).... then add your own answer below.

Comment: Will do this weekend, I have been away from Civ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was able to reproduce it and sure enough the tile stayed after a city was built.  But it seems to be unworkable.

Before:
[image: Where Hamburg use to be]

After:
[image]

Comment: so you've discovered a bug indeed

Comment: Are you able to use a worker to improve the tile to make it workable?